Angular Migration - No matching version found
I'm migrating my application from Angular 10 to Angular 11. When I do that, I get below error -
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @ruf/material@5.2.0-beta7.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

I checked and saw that indeed the specified version of the package (5.2.0-beta7) does not exist. I'm not sure where this version was mentioned as it is not mentioned in my package.json. I want to ignore if such missing targets are there instead of failing the migration operation. Is there any way to achieve this?
Update
I get this error after I execute ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force. When I try without --force I get error of incompatibility.

could you specify the official library for this package @ruf/material@5.2.0-beta7 ?

Actual @ruf is one of the libraries developed by my organization and there are some sub modules of it among which @ruf/material is a module which maybe used by other modules.

I solved my issue. I followed given steps -

Executed ng update.
I got list of dependencies I needed to update.
Executed ng update again, this time with all the dependencies as mentioned after after executing previous command. Also, specified the version which I needed to use.

This solved my issue. When your application is huge, given command for migration is not enough - ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force
You need to migrate all your dependencies too.
